# Is it possible to generate hbm xmls from Hibernate-annotated classes?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, migration

In one of the projects we have started off with annotation-based ORM. We have a requirement now to keep the Entity classes as plain Javabeans and not bring into it any other layer-specific detail. Because of this we want to moved to the approach of using HBM XMLs. Is there an easy method to do the migration.

Comment: adding annotations to class doesn't mean that they are **not POJOs.** You are going to loose number of advantages if you are moving away from annotations to XML. You have to seriously think about what you are going to do.

Comment: Thanks Manu! Yes I'm indeed aware of this fact. However we are planning to use them as backing beans and in a Drools-like business rules engine and to import these entities as domain classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work around writing all the mapping files manually would be having Hibernate generate the database schema based upon your annotated domain classes, against an actual DB (I would go for an in-memory one such as Derby). And then, you'll be able to use the Hibernate-tools plugin to generate the mapping files.

IMHO, depending on how many domain classes you have, this solution could go from saving you some time, to being a life-saver.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool, as far as I know. I was looking for a similar tool that would generate ejb-jar.xml file from annotated EJB-s 3.X and found nothing.

It is fairly easy to write a tool that would parse annotations in Java source code and then fill Velocity hbm.xml files templates with data taken from annotations.

Comment: However I am going with @KHY's option as that would be pretty quick and less error-prone.